# Convert Xamarin bitmap to byte[] not work or throw exception

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I tried to convert my image from camera to byte[] and then make request to my server but it is not working so my image from camera is

```
var image = textureView.Bitmap;
image = Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateBitmap
    (image,
    (int)OCR_Rectangle.GetX(),
    (int)OCR_Rectangle.GetY(),
    OCR_Rectangle.Width,
    OCR_Rectangle.Height);
```

My web request is

```
public async static Task<string> ParseAsync(byte[] image)
{
    string id = "my id ";
    string apiKey = "my api key ";
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("app_id", id);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("app_key", apiKey);
        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(image);
        var imageUri = "data:image/jpg;base64," + base64;
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { src = imageUri });
        var content = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("my website", content);
        var dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectLatex>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        return dynObj.latex;
    }
}
```

Here is my attempt to convert bitmap to byte[]

```
byte[] bitmapData;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
    bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
}
```

And then i want to use bitmapData in my request.But no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,  I found error this works

```
byte[] bitmapData;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
    bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
}
```

but i type wrong api key in my request